# Popup doesn't bind to Toggle when inside DataGrid (xceed)

Tags: wpf, listbox, popup, toggle, xceed

I've made a Toggle, which expands a Popup window with a `ListBox` inside. It looks like so:

```
<ToggleButton Name="Toggle" Height="20" Width="150" >
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="TestListPopup"/>
        <Popup Height="200" Width="150"
                            IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=Toggle, Path=IsChecked}"
                            PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Toggle}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="TypeSelectionChanged" >
                <ListBoxItem Content="Test1"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Test2"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Test3"/>
            </ListBox>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</ToggleButton>
```

It works perfectly, but I want to use it inside the `FilterRow` of my xceed `DataGrid` here:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="dataGrid"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSource}}">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
        <xcdg:TableflowView>
            <xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <xcdg:ColumnManagerRow/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <xcdg:FilterRow>
                        <xcdg:FilterCell FieldName="Name" IsEnabled="True"/>
                        <xcdg:FilterCell FieldName="Type" IsEnabled="True">
                            <!--  TestListPopup control here  -->
                        </xcdg:FilterCell>
                    </xcdg:FilterRow>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
        </xcdg:TableflowView>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Name" Title="Name" />
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Type" Title="Type" Width="160"/>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

In here though, the popup will not bind to the toggle button. Pressing the toggle button doesn't do anything.

I narrowed it down to the binding being broken, because if you set IsOpen="True", it's open (and not adhering to PlacementTarget), but again; it works perfectly outside of the DataGrid..

Why does a perfectly functional control break once put inside the `FilterRow`?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does a perfectly functional control break once put inside the `FilterRow`?

Because the `ToggleButton` and the `FilterCell` don't belong to the same [namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes).

You may try to bind using an `x:Reference`:

```
IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Source={x:Reference Toggle}}"
```

The other option would be to bind the `IsChecked` property of the `ToggleButton` to a `bool` property of a view model and also bind the `IsOpen` property of the `Popup` to the same source property. Make sure that the view model implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications when the source property is set.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a reasonable explanation. However the `x:Reference` solution puts the app into breakmode, with following error _Cannot call MarkupExtension.ProvideValue because of a cyclical dependency. Properties inside a MarkupExtension cannot reference objects that reference the result of the MarkupExtension_.

The other solution isn't really gonna work for me either, because I might want multiple controls pr grid/view and I dont want a bunch of IsOpenX-vars.

All that said you definitely gave me a big push in the right direction so thank you! :)

Comment: Okay I found out what was happening. Apparently a child cannot `x:Reference` its parent, so I just put the Popup beside the Toggle instead of inside it!